# Django serializer request JSON value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

used
django 2.0.2 MAC OS 10.13

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import RegisterSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
import json

class RegisterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ''
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    def create(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(json.loads(request.body))
        serializer_class = RegisterSerializer(json.loads(request.body))
        return Response(serializer_class)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import register
import uuid
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    UserEmail = serializers.EmailField(allow_blank=True,default=uuid.uuid4())
    UserPassword = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True,default=uuid.uuid4())
    UserSex = serializers.IntegerField(default=0)
    UserAge = serializers.IntegerField(default=0)
    DeviceId = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True,default=uuid.uuid4())
    PushKey = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True,default=uuid.uuid4())
    OS = serializers.IntegerField(default=0)
    OSVersion = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True,default=0)
    def create(self,validated_date):
        return True
```

api test.html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JocTQ.png)

i input this value
succese `print(json.loads(request.body))`
how to use this value at serializer

after

raise this exception

```
You passed a Serializer instance as data, but probably meant to pass serialized `.data` or `.error`. representation.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line
`return Response(serializer_class)` 
to 
`return Response(serializer_class.data)`